element_type Argument Defaults to False Instead of "text" in PySide6 Slot Connection
I'm building a PySide6 application on macOS, where I have a button that should add a new item with a default element_type of "text". However, whenever I click the button to add a new item, the element_type argument in my add_new_item function unexpectedly defaults to False instead of "text".
I'm not sure why element_type is being overridden or misinterpreted as False, as I've explicitly set it to "text" in the function definition.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
# Button to add new elements
self.add_button = QPushButton("Add Element")
self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add_new_item)

def add_new_item(self, element_type="text", content=None, element_id=None):
    # Create a new element with a unique ID if not provided
    if element_id is None:
        element_id = self.data_manager.add_element(element_type, content or f"Content of element {self.drag.blayout.count()}")

    # Create a visual representation of the element in the interface
    new_element = DragItem(content or f"Content of element {self.drag.blayout.count()}", element_id, self.data_manager)
    new_element.set_data(content or f"Content of element {self.drag.blayout.count()}")
    
    # Add the element to the interface
    self.drag.add_item(new_element)
    print("New element added")

What I've Tried:

Setting a default value for element_type as "text".

Using a lambda function in connect, like self.add_button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.add_new_item("text")). However, this caused the function to stop creating new elements altogether.



The second options should be valid (even using lambda: self.add_new_item(), since element_type is keyworded), so if it didn't work it may be because of other aspects of your code you're not sharing. Consider providing a proper [mre] and also run the program in a terminal or prompt to check for further output the IDE may not show.
